# c++ if several operator is defined in a class as virtual, does child need to override them all in order to compile?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, name-hiding

I have the following classes,

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void operator()(string a) {}
    virtual void operator()(int a) {}
};

class Child: public Base {
private:
    std::vector<double> child_vec;
public:
    void operator()(string a) override {
        cout << a << endl;
    }

};

int main() {
    Child child;
    child(9);
}
```

The above code snippet gives compile time error, ambiguous overload.
but if I put `virtual void operator()(int a) {}` as a normal function, it works,

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void operator()(string a) {}
    virtual void test(int a) {}
};

class Child: public Base {
private:
    std::vector<double> child_vec;
public:
    void operator()(string a) override {
        cout << a << endl;
    }

};

int main() {
    Child child;
    child.test(9);
}
```

Does that mean in case of several virtual operators in base class, I need to override all of them?

Comment: Don't get distracted by the use of operators here. Operators are just member functions with a funky syntax. If you understand overriding member functions you understand overriding operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `operator()` defined in `Child` hides `operator()`s defined in `Base`.

You can introduce them into `Child` via `using`.

```
class Child: public Base {
private:
    std::vector<double> child_vec;
public:
    using Base::operator();
    void operator()(string a) override {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};
```

In your 2nd code snippet you change the name to `test` then there's no such name hiding trouble.